# compare two intervals

Tags: confidence-interval, interval-arithmetic

I want to compare between two interval. What is the formula that I can use to compare two intervals and returns the biggest one?

**for example:**

interval1= [89.90, 92.25] interval2= [89.30, 93]

answer:

"interval ...  is bigger"

**example#2:**

interval1= [89.90, 92.25] interval2= [90.1, 93]

**example#3:**

interval1= [89.90, 92.25] interval2= [90.1, 92.1]

**example#4:**

interval1= [89.90, 92.25] interval2= [88.1, 92.1]

Comment: if $[a,b]$ then length of interval is $\left |b-a  \right |$

Comment: but the number of elements in each interval is uncountable

Comment: @gauravsaini: If you are not assuming $b \geq a$, you should use $(b - a)^+ \equiv \max\{b - a, 0\}$ instead of the absolute value since most people use the convention that $[a, b] = \emptyset$ when $a > b$.

Comment: For safety purpose.

Comment: @gauravsaini: Your answer is misleading/incorrect.

Comment: sorry but i am not interested in the size of interval. However i want to know if interval 1> interval 2 or vise versa.

Comment: @gauravsaini thanks for your help. Can you tell me haw to compare them respecting their values (magnitude).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Assuming $b \geq a$, the size of an interval $[a, b]$ is $b - a$.

Comment: thanks for your help. Can you tell me how to compare them respecting their values (magnitude).

Comment: Compare the two numbers. The bigger one is...the bigger one.